# casperJS keypress letter "A" on an html input text needs to populate

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have to scrape a website but I cannot login because it tracks events when typing inside the email and password input fields. The website is http://grow.zoominfo.com/#/signup. this is my code

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.sendKeys('#email_input', casper.page.event.key.Enter , {keepFocus: true});
    this.sendKeys('#email_input', 'david@mspseofactory.com', {keepFocus: true});
    this.sendKeys('#email_input', casper.page.event.key.Space , {keepFocus: true});


    this.sendKeys('#password_input', casper.page.event.key.Enter , {keepFocus: true});
    this.sendKeys('#password_input', "Babylon7", {keepFocus: true} );
    this.sendKeys('#password_input', casper.page.event.key.Space , {keepFocus: true});
    this.sendKeys('#password_input', casper.page.event.key.Backspace , {keepFocus: true});
    this.sendKeys('#password_input', casper.page.event.key.Enter , {keepFocus: true});  
});
```

but I still can't login because the input event listener did not detect any actual keypress on the input field. The website is using angular JS.

how do we trigger a keypress ang populate an HTML input text with the letter "A" in the google developer console?

Comment: `this.sendKeys('#email_input', casper.page.event.key.Enter , {keepFocus: true});` as the first event actually presses the enter key which would normally submit the form and remove focus. Have you tried to remove the first call?

Comment: yes I did that with no success. Actually, I have different versions of my code It's not working it seems that when using their website typing into #email_input changes the class of the input while using casperjs to fill up the input it does not change the class. Still I tried changing the class the same as when I am typing inside the input and submit the form. It is still detected.